# Failed to start The Apache Webserver

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

I just tried to configure SSL and I did ,but Apache can not start .It is so important for me .

**systemctl  status apache2.service**  :

```
apache2.service - The Apache Webserver
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-10-25 17:04:36 EDT; 17min ago
  Process: 7654 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/start_apache2 -DSYSTEMD -DFOREGROUND -k start (code=exited, >
 Main PID: 7654 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

---

**apache2ctl configtest**

```
 Syntax OK
```

---

**journalctl  -xe**

```
Oct 25 17:20:45 gheysari-na ksmserver[1996]: UnmapNotify: 60817441
Oct 25 17:20:45 gheysari-na ksmserver[1996]: UnmapNotify: 60817441
Oct 25 17:20:45 gheysari-na ksmserver[1996]: CreateNotify: 60817460
Oct 25 17:20:45 gheysari-na ksmserver[1996]: Grab Released
Oct 25 17:27:38 gheysari-na plasmashell[2029]: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence>
Oct 25 17:27:39 gheysari-na plasmashell[2029]: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence>
Oct 25 17:30:00 gheysari-na plasmashell[2029]: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence>
Oct 25 17:30:04 gheysari-na systemd[1]: Starting The Apache Webserver...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Oct 25 17:30:05 gheysari-na systemd[1]: apache2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu>
Oct 25 17:30:05 gheysari-na systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache Webserver.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Oct 25 17:30:05 gheysari-na systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 25 17:30:05 gheysari-na systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: This is not quite an answer but i'm sharing my knowledgde.. From my experience installing a SSL certificate is very delicate..
Couple of months ago i found this https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianother-apache
and since then i use this for my HTTPS config. Its very quick and handy. It can renew your certificates every x months. I think it's worth a look

Comment: What's the log data from `sudo systemctl -l status apache2`?  (Apache web logs don't get read properly without sudo)